# Use USB wired mouse connected on other as a wireless device

Tags: windows, macos, usb, mouse, bluetooth

I have a problem that goes like this. I have two laptops (MacBook Pro 2021 and Acer Nitro). I can connect my mouse and keyboard to my Acer laptop (USB) without any issues, but on MacBook I don't have the ports for them.

I was wondering if there is a way to maybe forward the signal from my Acer to the Mac in some way with Bluetooth or some software. I know that adapters could be used for this, but I'm wondering if there is some other solution.

Comment: Why overcomplicate things?  just get adapters or a USB C hub with type A ports.  You will spend way to much time trying to get "another solution" which probably wont work the way you want it.  Plus the adapters or hub will let you use more things.

Comment: Yeah, I know that fixes the issue and I have it already, but its not with me now, so I'm trying to have this as a temporary fix

Answer (score 0):

Use VNC.  Apple uses the VNC protocol for what they call "screen sharing" so any VNC client should do.  The video update may be slow but then if the computers are in close enough proximity for Bluetooth then you don't care, just use the screen on the Mac with the keyboard and mouse connected to the other computer.

To make this work enable "screen sharing" in the Sharing tab of System Preferences.  Once enabled the URL to sue for VNC will appear.

Do make note that VNC is not a secure protocol so if using this on a network that you cannot trust then it would be wise to look into ways to tunnel VNC through SSH, use a wired network between the computers, or some other ways to prevent others from picking up keystrokes over the network.